# Trying to extract mailing lists from .pck file

Tags: mailman, mailing-list

in short, our admin left our organization without properly handing over his duties and we don't have a replacement specialist yet. For some reason, the mail server stopped working and we don't have access to our mailboxes, but this is not the main problem, the immediate problem is that we don't have access to our mailing lists.

We have a backup of our mail server and there is a folder named lists which contains folders with the names of our mailing lists, each folder has 4 files "config.pck" "config.pck.last", "pending.pck", "request.pck".

I'm guessing that the lists are in one of these files, but I can't figure out how to convert/open them.

I can be wrong, but we use Mailman as mail server.

As you may have noticed I'm very far away from IT.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: **our admin left our organization without properly handing over his duties** - It isn't his responsibility to "hand over" his duties, it's your (the company) responsibility to ensure an orderly transfer of duties and responsibilities. Don't blame him for a failure on your part. That being said, if it were me I'd reach out to him with a monetary offer to act as a consultant for whatever time period is needed to affect the transfer of duties, responsibilities, and knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

There are mailing list configuration parameters, including members (subscribers) in those config.pck files. There is no editor for those AFAIK.

You are probably looking for messages - check them in archives/ folder rather than lists/ folder: e.g. if lists are in /var/lib/mailman/lists, check /var/lib/mailman/archives.

There should be files with "mbox" extension which contain messages and can be opened in text editor.